# Valid and invalid sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

***Problem:***
Which of the following are sets? assume that a proper universal set has been chosen and answer by listing the names of the collections of objects that are sets. warning: at least one of these items has an answer that, while likely, is not 100% certain.

***(i)***
$A = \{2,3,5,7,11,13,19\}$

***(ii)***
$B=\{A,E,I,O,U\}$

***(iii)***
$C=\{√x : x < 0\}$

***(iv)***
$D= \{1,2,A,5,B,Q,1,V\}$

***(v)*** $E$ is the list of first names of people in the 1972 phone book in lawrence kansas in the order they appear in the book. there were more than 35,000 people in lawrence that year.

***(vi)*** $F$ is a list of the weight, to the nearest kilogram, of all people that were in canada at any time in 2007.

***(vii)*** $G$ is a list of all weights, to the nearest kilogram, that at least one person in canada had in 2007.

***My try:***

*(i)*
The set is a valid set.
Because the collection is distinct and the objects in the set are well-defined.

*(ii)*
The set is a valid set because the collection is distinct and the objects are well-defined as they are vowels of English alphabetical letters.

*(iii)*
The set is a valid set because the collection is distinct and the objects are well-defined, although $x<0$ which doesn't hold for $√(x)$ in the real system, yet it makes sense negative number in radical in the complex system. However, a set can contain imaginary number.

*(iv)*
The set is not a valid set because the collection is not distinct as 1 is repeating two times, otherwise well-defined okay.

I want your ideas about (v), (vi) and (vii). It would be a great for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(iii) It does need to be stated that $x$ is in the domain of the real numbers. It is *assumed* that they are, but as it is not actually *stated* that they are, I would suggest that this set is actually not valid. Your teacher may not agree, as he or she may *expect* you to understand that the domain is the real numbers (depending on how advanced you are, you may not have officially encountered the classification of numbers into natural, integer, rational, real and complex). But given that fact, the set can be interpreted as containing the imaginary numbers.

(iv) In my understanding, D *is* actually a valid set, even though one of the elements has been defined twice. The fact that $1$ is *actually* only in the set once does not mean that it is necessarily "wrong" to specify it twice -- just that it is unnecessary. However, your teacher may disagree with this.

The rest are messy and tedious to think about. Horrible question. But here is a guess.

(v) E is *not* a valid set, as we are asked to provide the entries *in a given order*. A set does not recognise order. Hence what is being defined here is an "ordered tuple", otherwise known as a "finite sequence".

(vi) I believe that F and G *are* valid sets, but they are not possible to determine accurately. Besides, the weights of people change. But supposing it *is* possible to get the data. You would find that F and G are actually the same set.